# Wordpress Dashboard not loading

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress is installed in one site that I am working on. Suddenly in the admin panel i cant see any of the pan pages. I can click on the left side menu but nothing displays and there are no errors when i turn wordpress debug mode on.

I have searched around but I can not find a solution to my problem. any ideas on how to debug this or what could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Is there any error printed on server logs?

Comment: Have you done some inspects with chromes inspect element, or had a look the the source code to see if the content is being generated?

Comment: nothing in the error_log.log

Comment: @TheHumbleRat there is something being generated but dont know what it is. what i found by investigating that was an error hidden in the markup `Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: WP_Screen::$this in /var/www/vhosts/lonocreative.com/httpdocs/blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php on line 706` but dont know what it means. its on the following variable self::$this->_help_sidebar

Comment: This basically means you are trying to access a variable that does not exist. I would suggest you back up your site and database before doing anything. Then remove the plugin files one by one. If this does not solve the issue then you may have to do a restore with a fresh Wordpress install. But this is more than likely an outdated plugin causing an issue. Have you updated anything recently.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat i have changed the of the folders  of all the plugins so they should be de-activated? how can i deactivate them when i cant see the screen?

Comment: You will need to do this via the FTP folder ie remove them from the plugins folder or via the database. See these two links. Via database http://perishablepress.com/quickly-disable-or-enable-all-wordpress-plugins-via-the-database/. Via FTP http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-disable-all-plugins-through-phpmyadmin-site-down-500-error. Backing up is a definite must for this though as sometimes deactivating and reactivating a plugin can cause loss of settings. Which is a pain

Answer (score 8):

There is a bug in WordPress 3.3.1 causing the issue. It may affect other versions as well.

To solve the issue you can update WordPress to the current stable release and do integration testing afterwards. Or you can do a quick bug fix.

To fix the bug:

1. Open file blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php in your favorite text editor.
2. On line 706 find the following PHP statement: `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
3. Replace it with the statement: `<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
4. Save your changes.

Hope it helps you.

Link info: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/how-to-fix-empty-dashboard-issue-in-wordpress

Answer (score 2):

To fix the bug:

- Open file blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php in your favorite text editor.
- On line 706 find the following PHP statement: `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
- Replace it with the statement:`<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
- Save your changes.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` to the bottom of your `wp-config.php` file (just before the `require_once` line).